# How to run tezos rewards distributor for the past cycle?

Tags: baking, updates, tezos-reward-distributor, payment

After update my trd does not make payments for the last cycle. I use command:

`python3 src/main.py -C $CICLENO -V on -s -R -5 -M 3  --log-file=$CYCLENO.log`

where $CYCLENO is the cycle for which i want to pay.
Nothing particular is written even to the verbose logs. It ends with the following:

`2021-08-06 17:06:42,463 - MainThread - INFO - initial_cycle set to <some cycle>`

`2021-08-06 17:06:42,464 - MainThread - INFO - Producer "producer" started`

`2021-08-06 17:06:42,466 - MainThread - INFO - Consumer "consumer0" created`

`2021-08-06 17:06:42,466 - MainThread - INFO - Application is READY!`

`2021-08-06 17:06:42,467 - MainThread - INFO - -----------------------------------------`

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is related to the Granada update. TRD is not yet ready, so monitor https://github.com/tezos-reward-distributor-organization/tezos-reward-distributor/pull/474 for more info.